# get propertyValue of lambda expression in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In simple lambda expression like `model =>model.ID` I can get propertyValue in this way

```
 var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
 var propertyName = metaData.PropertyName;
 var propertyValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(propertyName).ToStringOrEmpty();
```

But how can I get the value(ID) from this expression `model => model.Docs.Customer.ID`
???
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelMetadata contains a property `object Model` that you can use to get the value of the model.

```
var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
var value = metaData.Model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you want nested type,try to do this way.

What you want in this case is an executable expression which will access the containing object of the property (e.g. get you the Docs property of the source object, or the Customer property of the Docs property of the source object). You also want the PropertyInfo of the target property (e.g. ID ). And you want both the property accessor and the PropertyInfo from the same expression.

This is not too difficult. It doesn’t require a stack of target objects and PropertyInfos as originally feared. Firstly store the PropertyInfo from the nested target in the normal way:

```
  targetPropertyInfo = targetExpression.AsPropertyInfo();
```

This gives us access to  ID . Then store the expression which retrieves the path to the containing object for the property from the original source - .Docs or .Customer.ID. In the expression tree, this is the expression which contains the root to the original parameter:

```
    if (targetExpression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
      {
    MemberExpression memberExpression = targetExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression.Expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Parameter)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = GetParameterExpression(memberExpression.Expression);
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            _targetExpression = Expression.Lambda(memberExpression.Expression, parameter);
         }
       }
     }
```

The key line is the one which contains Expression.Lambda(). The parent expression is a MemberExpression (e.g.  model.Docs.Customer) which itself is not executable. You can’t compile a MemberExpression and execute it on an object to get the member, as the expression needs to know the parameter it executes against.

Expression.Lambda creates a compilable, executable expression against a provided target parameter – which we already have from the “model” of the original expression, and we can find for any level of nesting:

```
 private ParameterExpression GetParameterExpression(Expression expression)
 {
     while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
     {
         expression = ((MemberExpression)expression).Expression;
     }
     if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
     {
         return (ParameterExpression)expression;
     }
     return null;
 }
```